# Arduino Uno microcontroller pin broke off

Tags: arduino, pins

The lowest left pin in my arduino uno microcontroller (ATMega328p) broke off. That would be pin PB0 (pin 14). I am wondering, would this have any effect on the microcontroller's functionality, or can I continue to use it if I just ignore this broken pin?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality of the micro-controller will not be compromised, assuming you didn't do anything else to the micro-controller. You won't be able to use that GPIO pin.

Comment: Choosing this answer since it was the first. Thanks.

Comment: _Sometimes_ it is possible to repair an IC's broken pin. You put the IC in a IC-holder, puts a pin taken from a discarded IC at the broken pin's position, and careffully put a drop of solder in the joint of the added pin and the broken pin in the IC edge. I just want to say that it CAN be done, but of course maybe you don't NEED to do it. Some people - like me - just like to FIX things, it's not because os money saving and surely it's not for time saving.

Answer (score 6):

Arduino uses PB0 as "Digital pin 8" which while it has some timer functionality not shared by all other pins, is not in any way critical to basic operation.

For example, it is not involved in the serial bootloader, power or reset, clock oscillator, or even required for ISP programming.

If you do decide to keep using this, you might clearly mark it somehow so that a year from now you don't waste hours trying to figure out why some downloaded example that tries to use this pin isn't working.

You can buy a new ATmega328p (do make sure to get the "p") relatively inexpensively, either already with the bootloader or without a bootloader which you would need to load via ISP.  But then you probably already knew that, as you presumably broke this by taking the chip out of the socket for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You should be ok as long as nothing else got damaged when the pin went, traces cut etc. and you know where the pin went.... that is, it is not hiding elsewhere shorting stuff out.